# How to write to a pointer in read only memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a particular character to the middle of a string pointed to by another pointer so that I can truncate the string. My program tries to eliminate leading/trailing spaces from the input. Since the pointer gets stored into read only memory, how can I go around it and add a '/0' character in between. Following is my code and i get a segmentation error at line 22 because of the afore mentioned problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

char *trim(char *s)
{
    while(isspace(*s))
        s++;
    char *end = s + strlen(s) - 1;
    while(end>=s && isspace(*end))
    {
        end--;
    }
    *(end + 1) = '\0'; //Line causing segmentation fault
    return s;

}

int main()
{
    char *e = NULL;
    e = trim("hello  ");
    printf("%s", e);
    printf("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "How can I write to read-only memory?" - Uh ... you can't. **That's the point!**

Answer (score 3):

You can't **write** in a **read-only** memory, but you can always store you string in the heap ( **not readonly** memory )
This is the way I would go :

> e = trim(strdup("hello  "));

It will copy the readonly string to a writable memory

---

EDIT: @Ankush pointed out the fact that the string is allocated, thus it will have to be **freed**

Comment: Note that the string should be `free()`'ed why it is no longer needed to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Note that `strdup()` is a POSIX function, commonly available, but not part of the official C Standard. Some users may need to [enable `strdup()` with a feature test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html), and others may need to write their own function.

Answer (score 3):

Since **read-only** memory is READ ONLY, you can use a `char` array instead of a string constant as an argument to `trim`.

```
char f[] = "Hello  ";
e = trim(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointer is not stored into the code memory , it depends on which 
type_qualifiers you are using to declare the pointer .

```
1 . char *ptr = "Stack overflow" ;
```

Now the ptr is stored into the stack memory and pointing towards the 
code memory , pointing in the sence it is storing the address of code memory .

```
2 . char *ptr = malloc(15);
    strcpy(ptr,"stack overflow");
```

Now also your pointer is stored in the stack memory and pointing towards the
 heap section(which is nothing but a extended data memory).

```
3 . char arr[15] , *ptr;
    strcpy(arr,"Stack overflow");
    ptr = arr ;
```

Now your pointer is stored into the stack and also pointing towards 
the array which is also stored into the stack section .

in case 1 , user is not allow to modify the string because the pointer is pointing to the code memory , but whereas in case 2 and case 3 ,
pointer can modify the string .

Answer (score 0):

in general string literals are stored in a read-only section (it depends on platform).
The C standard says that **string literals have static storage duration**, any attempt at modifying them gives **undefined behavior** , so **NEVER** attempt to modify string literals!

but you can do the followigs:

1 - initialize char array from string literal :

```
char ch_array[256] = "hello ";
```

2 - dynamically allocate memory for string:

```
    char* str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    strcpy(str, "hello ");

    .
    .
    .
    free(str);
```

3 - or use strdup() function( Keeping in mind it's actually not part of the ISO C standard itself, it's POSIX)